# Unique largest normal pi-subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\pi$ be a set of prime numbers. A finite group is said to be a $\pi$-group if every prime that divides its order lies in $\pi$. If $G$ is finite, show that $G$ has a unique largest normal $\pi$-subgroup (which may be trivial and may be all of $G$).

What I did: suppose $|G|=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\ldots p_n^{k_n}$. If $\pi$ contains a prime outside of the $p_i$'s, then the only $\pi$-subgroup is the trivial group. Then consider when $\pi$ contains a subset of the $p_i$'s, say $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_m$. I don't know what I can say about a subgroup whose order is divisible by $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a maximal normal $\pi$-subgroup of $G$ since $G$ is finite. If $H$ and $K$ are two such subgroups what can you say about $HK$?

Comment: Let's see... $HK$ is a normal subgroup since $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups. It is larger than $H$ and $K$. What is its order? We have $HK = \cup_{k\in K}Hk$, so it is the union of some cosets of $H$, and its order is divisible by $|H|$. But why are all its divisors in $\pi$?

Comment: Okay thanks Serkan, that finishes the problem then. Is that last result hard to prove? (Should I try it on my own, or should I look it up somewhere?)

Comment: It's relatively simple to prove. you should try it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ and $B$ be two normal $\pi$ subgroups of $G$. Then $AB$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Observe that $AB/B\cong A/(A\cap B)$ is a $\pi$ group. Since $|AB|=|B||AB/B|$ we have that $AB$ is a $\pi$ group. It follows that $$H=\bigcup_{N\unlhd G}^{\pi(N)\in\pi}N$$ is a well defined subgroup of $G$ which is normal and it is the largest normal $\pi$ subgroup of $G$. It can be seen as the product of all normal $\pi$ subgroups of $G$.

Ps.: For all finite groups $H$, $\pi(H)$ denotes the set of all primes dividing the order of $H$.